# Laravel Nested Collection Searching

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I've been stuck on this for several days.  I have a bunch of "rules" that I need to iterate thru, and it would make far more sense to use collections than a bunch of database calls.  The problem is I can't seem to get any of the solutions I've seen to work.

Below is a sample of the "rules" i'm trying to search on.  The tagId is the result I am looking for.  We have groups of tags, and an AND or OR operator on both the groupRules and the tagRules.

Essentially, id: 17 in my list below would read something like this:

(225 exists AND 235 exists) OR (232 exists AND 231 exists)

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to query anything other than the first level of each array.

The below functionality works just fine, but when I try to get down to the tagRules, or even the groupRules, it tells me it can't located the key groupRules.

```
$tagCollection = collect($tmp)
                        ->recursive()
                        ->where('tagType','!=',null);

[

    {
        "id": 17,
        "tagType": "CombinateTag",
        "name": "test1",
        "groupOperator": "OR",
        "groupRules": [
            {
                "tagOperator": "AND",
                "tagRules": [
                    {
                        "tagId": 225,
                        "hasTag": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "tagId": 235,
                        "hasTag": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "tagOperator": "AND",
                "tagRules": [
                    {
                        "tagId": 232,
                        "hasTag": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "tagId": 231,
                        "hasTag": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "tagType": "Composite",
        "name": "test1a",
        "groupOperator": "OR",
        "groupRules": [
            {
                "tagOperator": "AND",
                "tagRules": [
                    {
                        "tagId": 225,
                        "hasTag": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "tagId": 235,
                        "hasTag": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "tagOperator": "AND",
                "tagRules": [
                    {
                        "tagId": 232,
                        "hasTag": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "tagId": 231,
                        "hasTag": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

Comment: `it tells me it can't located the key groupRules` Can you show the code that's failing?

Answer (score 0):

This was a good one! It took me a while, but I think I got it.

Hope I understood what you want, if not maybe this helps you out. It's quite ugly, but you get the gist of it.

**So My first step was to make collection from your json:**

```
$tmp = json_decode('[

{
    "id": 17,
    "tagType": "CombinateTag",
    "name": "test1",
    "groupOperator": "OR",
    "groupRules": [
        {
            "tagOperator": "AND",
            "tagRules": [
                {
                    "tagId": 225,
                    "hasTag": 1
                },
                {
                    "tagId": 235,
                    "hasTag": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tagOperator": "AND",
            "tagRules": [
                {
                    "tagId": 232,
                    "hasTag": 0
                },
                {
                    "tagId": 231,
                    "hasTag": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 18,
    "tagType": "Composite",
    "name": "test1a",
    "groupOperator": "AND",
    "groupRules": [
        {
            "tagOperator": "AND",
            "tagRules": [
                {
                    "tagId": 225,
                    "hasTag": 1
                },
                {
                    "tagId": 235,
                    "hasTag": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tagOperator": "AND",
            "tagRules": [
                {
                    "tagId": 232,
                    "hasTag": 1
                },
                {
                    "tagId": 231,
                    "hasTag": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

]', true);

$tmp = collect($tmp)->recursiveCollect();
```

**With this:**

```
 \Illuminate\Support\Collection::macro('recursiveCollect', function () {
        return $this->map(function ($value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                return collect($value)->recursiveCollect();
            }
            if (is_object($value)) {
                return collect($value)->recursiveCollect();
            }

            return $value;
        });
    });
```

**Then I made a macro for your data:**

```
\Illuminate\Support\Collection::macro('roleFilter', function ($operator = '') {
        $property = '';
        if ($this->has('groupRules')) { //Check if the collection has more levels
            $operator = $this['groupOperator']; //set the operator
            $property = 'groupRules'; //Set the property aside
        }
        $res = false;
        if ($property === 'groupRules') { //Check if needs more digging
            $res = $this[$property]->roleFilter($operator);
        } else {
            if ($operator === 'OR') { //validate for OR between groupRules
                $res = false;
                $this->each(function ($val) use (&$res) {
                    $has = 0;
                    $val['tagRules']->each(function ($v) use (&$has) {
                        if ($v['hasTag'] == 1) {
                            $has++;
                        }
                    });
                    if ($val['tagOperator'] === 'OR') { //validate for OR between tagRules
                        $res = $res || $has > 0;
                    } elseif ($val['tagOperator'] === 'AND') { //validate for AND between tagRules
                        $res = $res || $val['tagRules']->count() == $has;
                    }
                });
            } elseif ($operator === 'AND') {  //validate for AND between groupRules
                $res = true;
                $this->each(function ($val) use (&$res) {
                    $has = 0;
                    $val['tagRules']->each(function ($v) use (&$has) {
                        if ($v['hasTag'] == 1) {
                            $has++;
                        }
                    });
                    if ($val['tagOperator'] === 'OR') { //validate for OR between tagRules
                        $res = $res && $has > 0;
                    } elseif ($val['tagOperator'] === 'AND') { //validate for AND between tagRules
                        $res = $res && $val['tagRules']->count() == $has;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return $res;
    });
```

**And you can check the roles like this:**

```
$alloweds = $tmp->filter(function ($value) {
        return $value->roleFilter();
    });
```

Comment: I will give this a try, and let you know how it goes.  Thank you so very much!

Comment: How would I pass an array of tags into the roleFilter you created?  Would this then pass out only the tags that matched the rules?

Comment: My macro cannot accept any parameters. It only filters the existing collection and returns the tag(s) that passes the validation.

Comment: Actually you can use where in after validating (and pluck if you only want the ids as a result):

$alloweds = $tmp->filter(function ($value) {
            return $value->roleFilter();
        })
            ->whereIn('id', [17, 18])
            ->pluck('id');

Comment: Thank you for the responses on this.  I did learned a lot about the collections from your post, but could not get the collection logic to return the results we needed.  We wound up doing this as an array loop with about 15 lines of code.